# Ng-repeat-start in angular2 - aka repeat multiple elements using NgFor

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I need to repeat several `li`-elements in a list in Angular2 for each item. In angular 1.x I used `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` for this. I can't find the right way to do it in Angular 2. There are [some older blog posts](http://jilles.me/ng-repeat-in-angular2-ng-for/) about this, but their suggestions don't work in the newest beta of Angular2.

All `<li>`-elements should be repeated for each category:
(which I would normally do with the attribute `*ngFor="#category of categories"` - but I can't find where to put it...

Help?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
        {{ category.title }}
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ '/music/' + tag.keyword }}" *ngFor="#tag of category.tags" [hidden]="tag.deleted === 1">{{ tag.tag_title_da }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>

    <li class="dropdown-header">Alle musikstykker</li>
    <li><a href="/music/all">Alle musikstykker</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you want to repeat the contents, use the `template` tag, and remove the `*` prefix on `ngFor`.

According to [Victor Savkin](http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax) on `ngFor` and `templates`:

> Angular treats template elements in a special way. They are used to
>   create views, chunks of DOM you can dynamically manipulate. The *
>   syntax is a shortcut that lets you avoid writing the whole 
>   element.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <template ngFor #category [ngForOf]="categories">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
        {{ category.title }}
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ '/music/' + tag.keyword }}" *ngFor="#tag of category.tags" [hidden]="tag.deleted === 1">{{ tag.tag_title_da }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>

    <li class="dropdown-header">Alle musikstykker</li>
    <li><a href="/music/all">Alle musikstykker</a></li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

**Update angular ^2.0.0**

You can use `ng-container` and just change `#var` to `let var`.

`<ng-container>` behaves the same as the `<template>` but allows to use the more common syntax.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
      {{ category.title }}
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ '/music/' + tag.keyword }}" *ngFor="let tag of category.tags" [hidden]="tag.deleted === 1">{{ tag.tag_title_da }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>

    <li class="dropdown-header">Alle musikstykker</li>
    <li><a href="/music/all">Alle musikstykker</a></li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to repeat all five ```<li>``` for each category, and I can't put a ```<div>``` in to wrap them without destroying the list...

Comment: The ```<li *ngFor="#tag of category.tags"> ... </li>``` you put in is another repeat inside the first repeat, that should work well.

Comment: If you put the parent `ngFor` on the `<ul>` tag, it will repeat the categories.

Comment: For your edit: I don't want the <ul> to repeat. Only its contents

Comment: Maybe it should be: `<template ngFor #category [ngForOf]="categories">`

Comment: Is this still working like that (2.0.0-rc.1)? I can't access the properties of category inside the loop.

Comment: Can you tell why this isn't working? http://plnkr.co/edit/0e796DfClochN9tmKrMO?p=preview

Comment: Works perfectly in Angular 4. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In the newer versions it works like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <template ngFor let-category [ngForOf]="categories">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
        {{ category.title }}
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ '/music/' + tag.keyword }}" *ngFor="#tag of category.tags" [hidden]="tag.deleted === 1">{{ tag.tag_title_da }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>

    <li class="dropdown-header">Alle musikstykker</li>
    <li><a href="/music/all">Alle musikstykker</a></li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

--> **let-category** instead of **#category**

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your effort, pixelbits, however the answer was different.

Reading about the asterisk in [Template Syntax in the Angular.io guides](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template) gives you the clue.

This solved it:

```
<template ngFor #category [ngForOf]="categories">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
        {{ category.title }}
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ '/music/' + tag.keyword }}" *ngFor="#tag of category.tags" [hidden]="tag.deleted === 1">{{ tag.tag_title_da }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
</template>
```

Comment: Just FYI, the [NgFor API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html) also shows the `<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="items">...</template>` syntax.  Too bad they don't highlight the fact that this syntax must be used to repeat multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks for that note

Comment: This syntax no longer works in angular 4.x.x, right guys? only `let`

Answer (score 1):

Worked with **5.2.x**

```
<ng-template ngFor let-category [ngForOf]="categories">
  <label class="value-fields_label">{{ category.name }}</label>
  <h3 class="value-fields_value">{{ category.title }}</h3>
</ng-template>
```