# Angular 2 *ngFor - Conditional wrapper element. Like using bootstrap row with three columns inside, then add a new row

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using `*ngFor` and it has me perplexed. I am trying to use UIkit but it would be applicable to Bootstrap also.

```
<div *ngFor="let device of devices" >
    <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
      <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-transform-origin-bottom-right uk-animation-scale-up">
        <h2 class="uk-h2">{{ device.name }}</h2>
          <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" (click)="toggleDevice(device)"  ng-disabled="device.onStatus == true">On</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="!device.onStatus" -->
          <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" (click)="toggleDevice(device)"  ng-disabled="device.onStatus == false">Off</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="device.onStatus" -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The element `div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid` needs be added at the start and after every 3rd element something like `i % 3 === 0` is what I was thinking, just nothing I try will make it render correctly. Any ideas would be greatly received.

EDIT - I need to have the view rendered like the lower image on [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh4MP.jpg) rather than the top image

EDIT 2 - Added the demo to [LINK](http://adamsackfield.tech/) As it loads is how it should look, working as only 3 elements. If you click sensors, this is how it is displayed using *ngIf tatements.

Comment: @torazaburo Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an aproach that utilises nested `*ngFor` to force wrapping 3 items in a `div`

First you will need a `getter` to split your array into threes.

```
get device_triples(){
    let arr = [];
    let triple= [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.devices.length; i++) {
        triple.push(this.devices[i - 1]);
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            arr.push(triple);
            triple= [];
        }
    }
    if(triple.length > 0){
        arr.push(triple);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This function will transform:

- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` into `[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]`
- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` into `[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5]]`

You could also use [`_.chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) for this

Then you will need to iterate over the new array in your template, add your "div of threes" and then iterate over each sub array, each with at most 3 items in:

```
<div *ngFor="let triple of device_triples">
    <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>    
        <div *ngFor="let device of triple">
            <h2 class="uk-h2">{{ device.name }}</h2>
            ...
       <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks to be exactly what I need. I will select it as best answer and the bounty is yours. Would I be able to impletement this inside a .ts file. Link to file I am referring too (https://github.com/Sacki2013/homeAutomation/blob/master/client/app/components/devices/devices.component.ts) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `index` that directive provides

like

`*ngFor="let device of devices ; let i = index"`

then in the html just check with `*ngIf` and add your block

like `<div ... *ngIf="i % 3 === 0"></div>`

Probaly you need this approach
[Ng-repeat-start in angular2 - aka repeat multiple elements using NgFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533200/ng-repeat-start-in-angular2-aka-repeat-multiple-elements-using-ngfor)

(in AngularJS 1.x it was pair of directives `ng-repeat-start` `ng-repeat-end`, now it's another approach for the same)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried this already but since the (lets call it row) element I want conditionally repeating has the other elements nested inside it, then it only adds the 1st, 4th etc to the DOM. I feel I need a way to add a wrapper element around the actual content. I can post some screenshots to imgur for clarity as i'm not sure I am wording it in the correct way.

Comment: Thanks again. Still lost, not sure what you are referring to in that link. Also torazaburo is correct i % 3 === 0 would apply to the first element making i === 0 redundant.

Comment: I feel since the element I need to add wraps around the other content and when I use conditionals it includes all the nested elements I need a way to remove the (uk-grid) element while still showing what is nested inside it.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer proposed, storing the `index` with something like `*ngFor="let device of devices ; let i = index"` will let you keep track of the index in the collection you're iterating over.

Then, as far as I understand you need correctly, you want to **conditionally apply a `class`** to elements, namely the first and every third. If you actually want a series like `T,F,F,T,F,F,T,F,F,T,...` then you can use `i % 3 === 0` to produce it and apply a `class` conditionally with something like

`<div (class)="i % 3 === 0 ? 'class-to-apply' : ''">`

This will let you conditionally add a class to the first and every third element afterwards.

If instead you want to have **different html** based on the index, then you have to use `ngIf` branching and have two html snippets to handle the two cases. Something in the lines of:

```
<div *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">first case</div>
<div *ngIf="i % 3 !== 0">second case</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. These methods won't suffice. Take adding the class, it will add it to the first element - say wrapping with <div class="row> iteration one</div>. As you see it will then close the row and iterate to the next and open a new row. This is the same for the ngIf - I could have 2 snippets as you say but after each iteration the row will be closed and a new one added. I have seen people suggest splitting the dataArray into smaller arrays and then use nested ngFors, just not sure how to implement that.

Comment: What I mean and don't think I was clear is after it open and closes the row on iteration 1, iteration 2 and 3 will be outside of this row and then it will open and close another row on iteration 4 and again the proceeding two will again be outside the row.

Comment: Added the demo to http://adamsackfield.tech/ As it loads is how it should look, working as only 3 elements. If you click sensors, this is how it is displayed using *ngIf tatements.

Answer (score 0):

@ChristopherMoore  have great answer but you need to modifythe devices_triple function 
to add a statement to check

```
if (i == this.devices.length){
   arr.push(triple);
}
```

this will help where cases like [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5]] and [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7]]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap V4.0, below link is useful.

[How to create a new row of cards using ngFor and bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746945)

In my case, it works for me as I am using Bootstrap V4.