# How to create a new row of cards using ngFor and bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4, ngfor

I'm trying to use the card group functionality of Bootstrap 4 with Angular `ngFor`.

Here is the HTML I have for now, but I can't find how to break to a new line after 3 items have been inserted:

```
<div class="row card-group">
    <div *ngFor="let presentation of presentations" class="col-4 card">
        <a [routerLink]="['/presentation', presentation._id]">{{presentation.title}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've seen other answer saying to use the clearfix class, but this has not worked so far for me.

Comment: Why use `card-group`? It doesn't allow wrapping the way a row>col does.

Comment: @zimSystem Because I want the cards to have the same height on within each row. So I basically want o mulitple rows of cardgroups

Comment: The `row` is already same height because BS4 uses flexbox. You don't need to iterate the `row`.

Answer (score 20):

You need a wrapping `div` with the class `col-4` arroud the `<div>` with `card` class. thats how grid layout works.

see using grid markup section here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#using-grid-markup

so:

```
<div class="row card-group">
    <div class="col-4"  *ngFor="let presentation of presentations">
        <div class="card">
            <a [routerLink]="['/presentation', presentation._id]">{{presentation.title}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8LDBMorXBB1OqI0bolS6?p=preview

Comment: It works but if the card content of the card don't have the same height, the card group are not sized appropriately see https://plnkr.co/edit/QeFpHMVyQwo81SsGfeTd?p=preview

Comment: yeah, that is not going to work without CSS changes. The only other option you have is to split the array into arrays of 3. here is a sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jUtAEEpyeGTYtVNUDLQS?p=preview. Note that with this approach, each 3 itesm will have the same height BUT not all items will. Note, expand the preview window to see it working.

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @zimSystem I found something that works.

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let presentation of presentations" class="col-4 card">
        <a [routerLink]="['/presentation', presentation._id]"><img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap"></a>
        <div class="card-block">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good job! I modified this way using your code - `<div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 card" *ngFor="let project of projects">
         ...
      </div>
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

The `card-group` is preventing the col's from wrapping to the next "line". Place the `card`s inside the columns, and instead use `h-100` to make the cards full/same height. This way the Angular code won't need to iterate the row.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                ..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
            ..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/yWdYL5GrTu

Comment: Unfortunately if the content of the text on each card is a different number of line, then the cards don't have the same height.

Comment: This works..but it stretches the height of the image

Comment: @DaveAAA what image? there's no mention of an image in the question.