# Angular2 [src] image loading twice as result of how *ngFor works

Tags: image, angular, ngfor

In child component ngOnChanges() is called twice for each array element.

this is my category.html

```
<ng-template ngFor let-fourlet [ngForOf]="productFourlets()" let-i="index">
    <div class="row" > 
        <pdp-product-list-item *ngFor="let product of fourlet" 
                                [product]="product" 
                                [category]="category" 
                                class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  product-item">
        </pdp-product-list-item>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

productFourlets() is function that returns array of arrays. Example here 
[Angular 2 *ngFor - Conditional wrapper element. Like using bootstap row with three columns inside, then add a new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268913/angular-2-ngfor-conditional-wrapper-element-like-using-bootstap-row-with-thr)

So something is really off here in pdp-product-list-item component elements are received via @Input() and then half a second pause and the same elements arrive again.

This causes all kind of problems in child component

Anyone experienced this ?

Comment: Do not call methods in template, all kinds of weird stuff happens :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876533/ngfor-running-an-infinite-loop-in-angular2

Comment: that was it.. write it as answer so i can accept

Comment: I'll mark it as a duplicate instead, as the answer in the linked answer  solves your issue. But glad to hear we got to the root problem quickly! :)