# Why NG-REPEAT doesn't work with json variable from service?

Tags: json, angular

I have a JSON variable in my StudentService.ts and I want to populate my select options from these JSON.

My service:

```
  careers : {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.selectedStudent = new Student();
    this.careers = [
      {"id":"itic", "name":"Sistemas"},
      {"id":"itic", "name":"Sistemas"},
      {"id":"itic", "name":"Sistemas"},
    ];
  }
```

My template.html

```
<p>{{ studentService.careers | json }}</p>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="career in studentService.careers">{{career.name}}</option>
  </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

The first line in `template.html` works, and shows my JSON, but I can't replicate that in my select.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular 2/4/5/6?

Comment: I'm using Angular 6. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ng-repeat-start in angular2 - aka repeat multiple elements using NgFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533200/ng-repeat-start-in-angular2-aka-repeat-multiple-elements-using-ngfor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular does not have **`ng-repeat`** , the corresponding syntax is **`ngFor`**, you need to change it using ngFor,

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let career of studentService.careers">{{career.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Before put question, I tried that method but it not worked. After all night, I realize it was a Materialize CSS framework error,  apparently "M.AutoInit();" does not autoInit all elements, Select Forms one of them. Thank you!